# Start Puppeteer headless but then show window afterwards?

Tags: puppeteer

Is it possible to start [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) headless but then, when an error occurs, show its window?

Answer (score 2):

No, headless and all the other configuration is set at the start.

I assume that you want to see what's going on the screen at some point; like an error. In this case you should take a screenshot:

```
await page.screenshot({ path: 'file_name.png' });
```